# Why is Camera.overrideSceneCullingMask an ulong?

Tags: unity-game-engine

In Unity you have 32 layers that [you can use](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Layers.html):

[image]

Therefore, [Camera.cullingMask](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera-cullingMask.html) is a 32-bit integer.

Why then is [Camera.overrideSceneCullingMask](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera-overrideSceneCullingMask.html) a 64-bit integer?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure but as I understand the [`overrideSceneCullingMask`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera-overrideSceneCullingMask.html) is for something different.

While the `cullingMask` covers exactly the amount of existing layers (32) the `overrideSceneCullingMask` sounds rather like a culling based on the scenes of which might exist more than 32 (though a bit unlikely)

See [`EditorSceneManager.SetSceneCullingMask`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SceneManagement.EditorSceneManager.SetSceneCullingMask.html)

> Set the culling mask on this scene to this value. Cameras will only render objects in Scenes that have the same bits set in their culling mask.

Comment: Forgot to mention, basically, what I'm looking for, is to selectively render layers on different scene views, e.g. render object A only in view 1, render object B only in view 2. This is possible and works, that's what `overrideSceneCullingMask` is for. Wondering if these extra 32 bits have anything to do with game view but so far I got nothing.

Comment: @aybe as said it is Scene based

Comment: I think I finally got it, indeed upper bits are reserved, see bottom in https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Layers.html but as usual it's cryptic, see result https://ibb.co/2NvQt55, blue is 29, red is 30, each on a single scene view as i wanted. Now, if I set upper bit 31 for scene, it shows in game view, don't need that but finally understood why. TL;DR; only match lower bits with scene/scene view and that's it.